# XSL file not link to XML file properly

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this problem with my xml file
This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
    <package>
        <productName>Cookies</productName>
        <servingSize>
            1
        </servingSize>
        <nutrition>
            <fat>
                <amount>11</amount>
                <unit>gram</unit>
            </fat>
            <saturatedFat>
                <amount>2</amount>
                <unit>gram</unit>
            </saturatedFat>
        </nutrition>
    </package>
```

And this is my XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system = "about:legacy-compat"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                <title>A4Q7</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>name: <xsl:value-of select = "package/productName"/></h2>
                <h2>size: <xsl:value-of select = "package/servingSize"/></h2>
                <table>
                    <thead><tr><td>Nutrition</td><td>Amount</td><td>Unit</td></tr></thead>
                    <xsl:for-each select = "package/nutrition/*">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="amount"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="unit"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've checked everything I could but when I opened up xsl document in broswers, empty is shown (except title and name/size)
So I want to know do I miss anything in my xsl file ?

Comment: I checked your files and they are OK. But due to recent "security changes" browsers impaired this XML/XSLT scenario. In Firefox, for example, you can bypass these new restriction by changing `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` to FALSE in the `about:config` settings.

Comment: Thank you! Now I can see my table !